# Mathematical logic - problem in basic modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Anybody out there who can point me in the right direction with this problem:

> Consider the dual $D^∗$ of the distribution principle:
>
> $$D^∗ :\diamond(p \to q) \to (\diamond p \to \diamond q)$$
>
> What property of frames does $D^∗$ characterize?
>
> Give a proof of your answer, at least an outline of the proof that indicates the crucial steps.

I have done a proof myself, but I am not entirely sure, that it is indeed correct. I know that the distribution axiom of modal logic holds for all possible frames and worlds. Since that holds for any frame, I have just shown, that since it holds necessarily, it must be possible, and from that, i can deduce, that D* must hold for all frames.

Comment: what does the diamond mean?

Comment: The diamond denotes 'possibly' in modal logic.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. Including your thought and what you have tried tend to attract more response for this site. welcome to maths stack exchange. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 also here is a mathjax reference for typesetting maths.

Comment: I have formatted the question under the assumption that everything after the first line ("... this problem:") is a quotation from a problem in a book or problem set you have received. If that is not the correct structure of the question, please adjust or roll back the edit as needed.

Comment: Hi, Siong. You are probably right. I have added my thoughts to the original post.

Comment: As for where your proof goes wrong, since this might help: It's true that if $\square p$ then $\diamond p$ at all non-terminal worlds (and that caveat is already a sign that there's something wrong), but the core problem with your logic is that if $a\implies b$, $a\implies a_1$ and $b\implies b_1$, it's true that $a\implies b_1$, but _not_ true that $a_1\implies b_1$!

Comment: It's worth thinking of the left hand side of an implication as 'backwards' - while you can draw 'weaker' conclusions from an implication, you can only conclude the same conclusion from a _stronger_ premise, not a weaker one - and $\diamond p$ isn't a stronger premise than $\square p$. Try writing your implications $x\implies y$ in the form $y|\neg x$ and play with your modalities to see what you can see.

Comment: Hey, Steven: Thank you for your insight. I guess the main problem is, that I do not know what the final step of the proof is or what the proof should look like.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Hi Steven.. I have been drawing models for 4 hours straight now. And i can't seem to find one, that satisfies this formula. Is this the right answer, that it does not exist?

Comment: @Sebastian What about one where $p$ and $q$ hold in all worlds? Then $p\implies q$ is true in all worlds, $\diamond p$ and $\diamond q$ are true in all but the leaf worlds, so $\diamond p\implies \diamond q$ is true in all worlds, and therefore the statement $D^*$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion can't be true: Here is a model where (an instance of) $D^*$ is false:

Worlds $\{w_0, w_1, w_2\}$ with $w_0\rightsquigarrow w_1$ and $w_0\rightsquigarrow w_2$.
$q$ never holds; $p$ holds at $w_2$ only.

Then $p\to q$ holds at $w_1$ and therefore $\Diamond(p\to q)$ at $w_0$.

Similarly, since $p$ holds at $w_2$ we have $\Diamond p$ at $w_0$.

But we *don't* have $\Diamond q$ at $w_0$; so $\Diamond(p\to q)\to \Diamond p \to \Diamond q$ is false.

Comment: Hi Henning, Thank you for your response. Does this mean, that D* fails for any frame?

Comment: @Sebastian: It means that there is at least one frame that $D^*$ fails for.

Comment: I see. But what is the strategy to prove what property of frames D∗ characterizes? Is it just brute force? To look if it is serial, reflexive, transitive and so on?

Comment: @Sebastian: I would proceed by trying to figure out what one needs of the frame to be able to construct a _counterexample_ such as the above.

Comment: I will try. But I am not entirely sure about how I would do that. And thank you for response again!

Answer (score 0):

The system defined by the axiom
 $$\Diamond(p \to q) \to (\Diamond p \to \Diamond q)\tag{1}$$
is one that I call $\mathbf{K}_u$ and which is characterized by the following class of frames: each world sees either $0$ or $1$ worlds (possibly itself).

You can try to prove this directly from $(1)$. Or you can see that it is the same system as defined by the axiom:
 $$\Diamond p \to \square p\tag{2}$$
by showing that $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be inferred from each other. Then you can see that $(2)$ pretty much says: "if $V(p)=1$ in one world seen by $w$, then $V(p)=1$ in all the worlds seen by $w$". Which obviously cannot be the case when $w$ sees $2$ or more worlds.

Here is how one can show the equivalence between the two axioms:

- $(1)$ implies $(2)$: substitute $(p,q)$ with $(\neg p, F)$ in $(1)$ and you immediately get $(2)$ because $\Diamond F$ is $\mathbf{K}$-equivalent to $F$.
- $(2)$ implies $(1)$: substitute $p$ with $p \to q$ in $(2)$ and you get
  $\Diamond(p \to q) \to \square(p \to q)$. Then use $\mathbf{K}$-tautology 
  $\square(p \to q) \to (\Diamond p \to \Diamond q)$ and you get $(1)$ by transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Henning's response:

I would try to construct a proof that your formula is valid everywhere and see where it breaks down. It might go something like this:

Let $(W,R)$ be a frame and let $v: W\times\{p,q\} \rightarrow \{\text{T, F}\}$ be a truth assignment.

Suppose $a\in W$. If $a\not\vDash \Diamond(p\rightarrow q)$, then we are done, so suppose $\Diamond (p\rightarrow q)$ is true at $a$. We want to show $\Diamond p \rightarrow \Diamond q$ is true at $a$, so, similarly as before, assume $\Diamond p$ is true at $a$.

Thus there is a $b\in W$ accessible from $a$ so that $p\rightarrow q$ is true at $b$, and there is a $c\in W$ accessible from $a$ so that $p$ is true at $c$. If $b = c$, then we would be done. But there doesn't seem to be a way to prove that $b= c$...

Ok, so now we have an idea of what we need to be true: We need the word $b$ that $a$ sees to be the same world as the world $c$ that $a$ sees. How could we put restrictions on our frame so that whenever we see a world $b$ where $p\rightarrow q$ and a world $c$ where $p$, then those are the same world?